# Dataset format for copying csv files from a sftp server to blob storage

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I want to copy csv files from a sftp server to blob storage using copy activity of adf without processing the content. Is there a difference using a binary dataset instead of a csv dataset for the source and sink?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the ask correctly, you want to copy csv files from SFTP to blob storage as-is. If that is the case, you can use [binary dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary) on both source and sink of your copy activity. When using Binary dataset, the service does not parse file content but treat it as-is. Where as if you use CSV file format, the service will parse file content and you will have to configuration file specs in the connection settings of your dataset.

Please note that when using Binary dataset in copy activity, you can only copy from Binary dataset to Binary dataset.